# Gridlayout rows one inside another

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm new to NativeScript. I cannot get a simple table layout to look good through the gridlayout container. Here's my markup

```
<GridLayout columns="*, 100, 100" rows="auto">
  <Label text="ΕΣΟΔΑ" row="0" col="0" colSpan="3" fontSize="20" class="font-weight-bold"></Label>
  <Label text="Έσοδα Παροχής Υπηρεσιών" row="1" col="0" fontSize="20"></Label>
  <TextField 
       row="1" col="1"
       keyboardType="number"
       returnKeyType="done" 
       class="input input-border"></TextField>
  <Label text="50%" textAlignment="right" row="1" col="2" backgroundColor="green" fontSize="20" verticalAlignment="middle"></Label>
</GridLayout>
```

and this is the output

[image]

I want the first label to span the entire first row. I tried changing the col values or removing col, nothing worked.

Comment: the answer is here....stupid me.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31626532/nativescript-gridlayout-rows-overlapping?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one 1 row, you need 2 or more
`<GridLayout columns="*, 100, 100" rows="auto,auto">`
That should sort your views